# Deleting item using ajax request and sweet alert2 in Laravel-8

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, laravel-8

everyone I need your help I am working on my final year project and faced a problem which ruined my whole day. Sweet alert is showing properly but after submitting the alert to be deleted its not working and not going for request. Here is my button and js code.

Thanks in advance

### submit button or anchor

```
<div class="menu-item px-3">
  <a href="#" class="menu-link px-3 delete" id="{{$agent->id}}">Delete</a>
</div>
```

### Js code

```
<a>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</a>
<script>


    $(document).on('click','.delete',function() 
    {

        console.log('hi before');   

        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
            }).then((result) => {
            if (result.value) 
            {
                console.log('hi after');   
        
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var url = '{{ route("agent.destroy", ":agent") }}';
                url = url.replace(':agent', id);
                $.ajax
                ({
                    headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                    url:url,
                    type:'DELETE',
                    datatype:'json',
                    data: {
                
                "_method": 'DELETE',
               
            },
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    });
</scrip>
```

Comment: Any Js errors in the console window? Does the console.log line output correctly? - Shouldn't you be using the isConfirmed /isDenied methods in SA2?

Comment: I've tried the JS part in codepen and apart from `type` not being recognised by Swal it seems ok; 1) check if your ajax call appears in `Network` tab (dev tools) 2) if it does, check the response from server (and/or implement `failure` callback in the ajax request as well

Comment: Thank you ->James and ->Peter, I found the solution and it was something different from what I was thought. Love from heart to both of you brothers

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer and ad csrf meta tag in the head section of master page

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```